# imagettftext only availablöe in PHP 7.2 and not in 8.1?

Tags: php, imagettftext

I am using the following code to display a capcha

```
    $img = ImageCreateFromPNG('captcha2.png');
    $color = ImageColorAllocate($img, 140, 140, 140);
    $ttf = 'bodoni_bk_bt.ttf';
    $ttfsize = 32;
    $angle = rand(-8,8);
    $t_x = rand(5,50);
    $t_y = 50;
    imagettftext($img, $ttfsize, $angle, $t_x, $t_y, $color, $ttf, $text);
    imagepng($img);
    imagedestroy($img);
```

In one of my websites (at ionos.de - former 1und1) the capcha-text is only being displayed under PHP 7.2.
Switching to 7.4 or higher the function is no longer available.

On another website of mine the code is working perfectly under PHP 8.1.
Does somebody has an idea what is going on or has an solution?

Manfred

Comment: These functions are part of the GD module, and are supported through version 8. The module is however, optional, and not always installed by default. You likely simply have to install it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since the website is hosted by a professional provider, I can not install anything. The support said, that there ie is noboby to solve this problem.

Comment: Don't you have a control panel for your account, where you can install things and enable modules?

Comment: Unfortunately not. This a older basic-account for our dance-club and they wanted to save money. 8-(

Comment: Sounds like it's time for a new host.